# Any way of telling if the user has the date and time to automatic or not on ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know that for android I can get it by using the Settings class, Any way of doing it with ios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way if you'll use it in an AppStore app. The API to get this data is private. Thus the corresponding key is undocumented, and it might be changed at any time (or it's already been changed, idk). However, if you still need this data for personal use, check this:

```
NSDictionary *pref = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] persistentDomainForName:@"com.apple.timed"];
BOOL isAutoTimeEnabled = [[pref objectForKey:@"TMAutomaticTimeEnabled"] boolValue];
```